# Opensource test management tool thats being used for both agile and waterfall

Tags: test-management

I am looking for some open source test management tool that should go well  both for agile and waterfall and can integrate with TFS.
Anybody using something like this and have reviews that will be great.
We are ok with smaller budgets like 5k per year too.

Thanks

Comment: If you vote to close (I did not), please add a comment what is wrong about the question. Current question, even if not worded perfectly, is a valid concern for our exact target audience here. Even if you have enough XP so you  *can* vote to close, it does not mean you should. It might be abuse of your powers. You know the drill: *with great power come great responsibility* :-)

Comment: Also, OP: FYI there is another forum:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where this question is on-topic. But there, audience is more generic, aimed for personal use. Here, we do QA for living. I like the question to stay here.

Answer (score 2):

I would use VSTS with git

- VSTS works with TFS
- VSTS also works with GIT which is now the de-facto tool for code repository management, even MS
- VSTS has project boards just like Jira, Trello, etc.

Comment: We do not have Jira inhouse